# How to click on specific download link when there are number of divs containing download link with Selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to download F&O Bhavcopy from

> "https://www.nseindia.com/all-reports-derivatives#cr_deriv_equity_archives"

using selenium in Python.

F&O Bhavcopy is in 1 of the div.there is download link in that div.

I have tried folowwing code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card-body']/span[@class='reportDownloadIcon']/a[@class='pdf-download-link']"))).click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/span[@class='reportDownloadIcon']/a").click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.card-body span.reportDownloadIcon a.pdf-download-link").click()
```

Nothing worked for me.because there are number of div's which consist of download link. I want to click on specific download link .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is Html of element?  What is error you are getting?

Comment: Timeout error..driver is not able to find that element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the download button of F&O Bhavcopy(csv) by using the below xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card-body']//label[contains(text(),'F&O - Bhavcopy(csv)')]//following-sibling::span[@class='reportDownloadIcon']"))).click()
```

And if you click on download button of F&O - Bhavcopy (fo.zip) then you can use:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card-body']//label[contains(text(),'F&O - Bhavcopy (fo.zip)')]//following-sibling::span[@class='reportDownloadIcon']"))).click()
```

***Addition to the answer***

Clicking to the button using JavaScriptExecutor click

```
downloadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='card-body']//label[contains(text(),'F&O - Bhavcopy(csv)')]//following-sibling::span[@class='reportDownloadIcon']//a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", downloadButton)
```

Comment: Not working for me...getting error..ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="reportDownloadIcon">...</span> is not clickable at point (872, 877). Other element would receive the click: <li>...</li>
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)

Comment: @Prats I have added another way to click on the element and that is working fine, please click the new way to click on the element.

Comment: With your new addition,yes it is clicking on download link.. but file is not downloading showing error that Please try after some time.

Comment: @Prats then thats your webpage error, you can try clicking it after sometime.

Comment: still it is showing...Error in downloading file.Please try after sometime.

Comment: @Prats you can try with download button of any other file because its an error from the webpage and you dont have any control on it.

Comment: i have tried with other files also...it is not downloading...how it is possible that it is web page error...

Comment: @Prats It is possible that they have put in a bot detection and due to which it is not getting downloaded

Comment: is there any other way to download

Comment: @Prats you can check it from your developer

Comment: I have checked same code on my home pc also..showing same error..Error in downloading file.Please try after sometime.

Comment: @Prats If they have put a bot detection, then it would not work from any network. You need to check with the developer in this case.

Comment: I am really sorry..but i am not getting you..who is the developer. ...you have downloaded file using that same  code... how ?

Comment: @Prats  Developer is the one who has developed this website, are you automating your own website or someone else's?

Comment: Automating for my own project

Answer (score 0):

Use `a[onclick*=cr_deriv_equity_archives]` css selector to download, but first you have to select the date on the page:

```
driver.get('https://www.nseindia.com/all-reports-derivatives#cr_deriv_equity_archives')
cards = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cr_deriv_equity_archives .card")))

# select date
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", 
                      driver.find_element_by_id("cr_deriv_equity_archives_date"), "01-Jan-2020")
for card in cards:
    card.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=cr_deriv_equity_archives]").click()
```